# Vertical ordered tabs in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a vertical list of files that are currently opened pinned somewhere on the screen. Visual Studio 2017 has a feature that does exactly what I prefer, but I have to click it open to view it.

This image shows the feature I'd like to have pinned somewhere on the screen. (See right-top of the image)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by installing [Productivity Power Tools 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017). If you don't want the entire toolset, you can use just the [Custom Document Well](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell) to get the vertical tabs.